# Haproxy 1.5 - Usage of multiple certificates (wildcard)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, haproxy, domain-name, ssl-certificate-errors

I'm running multiple apps behind Haproxy 1.5.
We have a signed SSL wildcard certificate for our domains: ***.mysite.com**

We need now to implement **4th level domains: *.dev.mysite.com**
The SSL certificate set up for *.mysite.com will not work in that case.
I therefore created a self signed certificate for the common name: ***.dev.mysite.com**

And I'm now trying to add this certificate into Haproxy.
But it seems that **only the first certificate for *.mysite.com is taken in consideration** by Haproxy and ***.dev.mysite.com** doesn't seems to be interpreted.

My configuration:

```
frontend mainHttps
    bind *:433 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/sites/combined.pem
    [...]
```

Where *combined.pem* contains the signed certificate for *.mysite.com and the self signed certificate for *.dev.mysite.com

**Note:**
The behavior of Haproxy 1.5 concerning the binding of SSL certificated is different than the behavior of Haproxy 1.6 [as explained here](https://serverfault.com/questions/721687/how-to-configure-haproxy-for-multiple-ssl-certificates)

I'm not sure if the issue is linked to Haproxy version or if the problem is linked to the usage of the wildcard certificate *.mysite.com which take over on *.dev.mysite.com

**Edit:**
I tried to use the following syntax as well:

```
frontend mainHttps
    bind *:433 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/sites/
    [...]
```

Where */etc/ssl/private/sites/* contains two different pem certificates. This syntax seems not to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found a simple solution with Haproxy 1.5, but I've applied a workaround that solved my issue as explained below **using multiple load balancers**.
It's not ideal for sure, so my ultimate solution was to **upgrade to Haproxy 1.6**.

**Usage of multiple load balancers:**

It's the advantage of working on a HA infrastructure. I'm using a floating IP as my main entry point, which will then reach an available load balancer over Haproxy.

Therefore, I assigned a load balancer to my services that will use the *.dev.mysite.com self signed certificate.

```
frontend mainHttps
    bind *:433 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/sites/dev.mysite.pem
    [...]
```

And I've edited the DNS records so *.dev.mysite.com is redirected to this specific load balancer now dedicated to serve my 4th level domain.

**Upgrade to Haproxy 1.6:**

As the workaround below is an expensive solution, you might want consider upgrading to Haproxy 1.6 that solve the issue by allowing the binding of multiple certificates:

```
frontend mainHttps
    bind *:433 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/dev.mysite.pem crt /etc/ssl/private/mysite.pem
    [...]
```