# How to use multiple SSL certificates in HA Proxy

Tags: haproxy

I currently have HA Proxy working with domain1.com, and am looking to add a domain2.com, I'm having a hard time finding documentation to support the adding of a second SSL certificate for SSL termination though, and was hoping for some assistance.

Current config:

```
frontend http-in:
    bind *:80
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc}

frontend https-in:
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/domain1.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    acl letsencrypt-acl path_beg /.wellknown/acme-challenge/
    use_backend letsencrypt-backend if letsencrypt-acl

    acl domain1.com hdr_beg(host) -i domain1.com
    use_backend domain1.com if domain1.com

    acl demo.domain1.com hdr_beg(host) -i domain1.com
    use_backend domain1.com if domain1.com
```

Desired/attempted config:

```
frontend http-in:
    bind *:80
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc}

frontend https-in:
    bind *.domain1.com:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/domain1.pem
    bind *.domain2.com:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/domain2.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    acl letsencrypt-acl path_beg /.wellknown/acme-challenge/
    use_backend letsencrypt-backend if letsencrypt-acl

    acl domain1.com hdr_beg(host) -i domain1.com
    use_backend domain1.com if domain1.com

    acl demo.domain1.com hdr_beg(host) -i domain1.com
    use_backend domain1.com if domain1.com

    acl domain2.com hdr_beg(host) -i domain2.com
    use_backend domain2.com if domain2.com
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, my attempted/desired config errors out generically telling me the config is wrong, so I'm sure there's a more correct way of going about this, help and suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/560978/configure-multiple-ssl-certificates-in-haproxy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure multiple SSL certificates in Haproxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/560978/configure-multiple-ssl-certificates-in-haproxy)